# How to make a Line take full width of the column it is in (UWP)

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a line like this

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Line  x:Name="DashedBorderElement" Stroke="Red"  Grid.Column="0" StrokeThickness="2"  />
</Grid>
```

This line won't be visible until I give`X2="100"` to it. I do not want to give any specific width to this line, I want the Line to take the width of the Grid Column it is in. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the X2 value to parents width

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Line  x:Name="DashedBorderElement" X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" Stroke="Red" Grid.Column="0" StrokeThickness="2"  />
        </Grid>
```

**Edit:** 
if you want the exact width of the grid column itself change it to:

```
<Line  x:Name="DashedBorderElement" X2="{Binding Path= ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}" Stroke="Red" Grid.Column="0" StrokeThickness="2" ClipToBounds="False" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than binding the X2 property of a Line would be a Rectangle, which is stretched automatically when you don't set its Width:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```